# Is it possible to make libcurl compressing data of the http messages?

Tags: http, curl, gzip, libcurl

I make a search and I found that the `libcurl` is able to decompress received data (compressed with  gzip for example) using the following option:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
```

But I can not find how to make the `libcurl` sending a compressed data of the http messages?

Does the `libcurl` support compressing data of the http messages that going to be sent? If yes how I can configure that in my http curl client?

Comment: No you need to compress your data yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard way in HTTP to compress the data (and have the server understand that and decompress). You need to manually compress and send it and you must make sure the receiver understands the compression if it should be capable of decompressing it.

Comment: How to add a new style to the http header with libcurl? In fact I want to add the style "Content-Encoding" to the http header

Comment: Use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to pass on your own headers.